# How can I download source code from Linux Cross Reference library (generated by LXR engine)?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, lxr

I wanted to download Linux kernel module source code from http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bluetooth/. Is there any tool like SVN to download the source code generated by LXR engine? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer, here is a procedure based on a low documented feature of LXR.

1. Display the file you are interested in
2. Modify the URL in the browser address bar, adding at the end `?_raw=1` and go there (i.e. press return key)
3. The file is then displayed "as is", without any decoration (it is sent as `text/plain`)
4. You can now save the file from browser menu command File->Save as

NOTES:

1. The `?_raw=1` argument can be used to have HTML files interpreted by your browser, i.e. displayed as HTML because they will be sent as `text/html`.
2. The feature has been present in LXR for ages, though in versions older than 0.10 the argument is spelled `?raw=1` (without underscore).
3. I checked that `?raw=1` works with free-electrons though they use 0.3.1 which was released in 2003!

Comment: I tried this trick ([after adding _raw=1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bluetooth/6lowpan.c?_raw=1)) but didnt helped. Page is showing with the decorations

Comment: Please give the complete URL you used. Which is LXR version? (recent release show the version number in the bottom line)

Comment: Yes, the trick allows only the currently displayed file to be downloaded.

Comment: I am using 4.0 version with this [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bluetooth/). But I want some mechanism to download all the files and directories downloaded automatically like in svn, github

Comment: The link you provided points to a 0.3.1 LXR (which is a very very old LXR release). Nevertheless, the trick should work. But, the trick is not intended to do a bulk download of a source tree. It is only a "complimentary" feature for occasional download. The global download is a service outside LXR, it should be provided under an appropriate form by the source tree provider, like svn or github as you point out. Sorry for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah you right I am using LXR 0.3.1 version and bluetooth library version with 4.0. At least whatever the trick you are giving that is working. But I was searching for some recursive mechanism.

Comment: @HariOmPrakash Unfortunately, there is no recursive mechanisme inside LXR. You could eventually write a script to do that for a single directory: capture the source code for a directory listing, parse it (directories are HTML-tagged, so you could even recursively call the script for sub-directories) and launch a text-only browser such as mutt or curl to doxnload individual files with the appropriately crafted URL. Anyway, I strongly suggest you switch to latest LXR release since you'll get a tremendous improvement on indexing performance and a much easier installation and configuration process

Comment: I got it! I will try what you have said. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on lxr states that there is a git repo.
http://lxr.linux.no/
I have never tried it, but it may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I was looking for a related thing - the possibility to download individual C files from LXR as plain text. If it was possible to download files as text, in principle you could write some sort of a parser/automatic downloader for a whole directory.

The documentation for the LXR engine seems to be here:

- [LXR Cross Referencer - Browse /doc at SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/files/doc/)

... and as far as I could see from the 1.0 PDF manual (note that lxr.free-electrons.com seems to run on version 0.3.1, though), there is no mention of plain-text source files being exported (in addition) to the HTML.

So, very likely, as the plain-text source files seem not to be available in an LXR export, there will be no tool that will be able to download. (*Btw, I too wish there was a tool like this, otherwise the only option is to clone the entire Linux source tree via git*).

Note, however, that there is also an experimental version of LXR from lxr.linux.no ; that one generates HTML that requires JavaScript, and it will show a "download" button in its interface; then one can download the plain-text source file. As lxr.linux.no is down for me for the moment, here's a link to an annotated HTML page to another site, that seems to use the same engine (there is no note ATM for the LXR engine numeric version):

- http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v2.6.38/sound/drivers/dummy.c

... and this is how the link looks like to obtain plain-text version:

- http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.38/+save=sound/drivers/dummy.c

Note that this is a different URL format than what lxr.free-electrons.com would use:

- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/drivers/dummy.c?v=2.6.38

... and there is a note on the start page ( http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/ )
once you enable JavaScript, which states that:

> lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com is currently running an experimental fork of the LXR software provided by lxr.linux.no.

... or, in other words: the link format for downloading plain-text source files from lxr.linux.no, will not work for the (current) lxr.free-electrons.com installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can browse the references and also can download the source file
https://code-grep.com/view/project/54b083273b2082684a000008/linux-3.19-rc2

Comment: Individually is possible but I cannot download the whole directory contents at once.

Answer (score 0):

On free-electrons.com, it works by adding the argument "**raw=1**" in the URL. For example, this URL...

`http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/misc/lis3lv02d/lis3lv02d.c?v=3.8`

... will become this :

`http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/misc/lis3lv02d/lis3lv02d.c?v=3.8&raw=1`

The resulting page can then be saved using the "file saving" feature of your browser. On Linux and Windows, this is usually mapped to the `ctrl+s` keyboard shortcut.